# Help with rails collection select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, helper

I need to add different values for each option tag in my collection_select cause Im trying to use [this jquery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/DependentSelectbySilVeR).... How do I do that?

Heres my collection select code

```
<%= e.collection_select(:id,State.all,:id,:name) %>
```

The output should be something like

```
<select name="state[id]" id="state_id" class="selectable">
<option value="">-- select --</option>
<option value="1" title="florida">Florida</option>
<option value="2" title="georgia">Georgia</option>
</select>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I believe you gotta write your own helper to do so.